# Teacher representation in Moodle database

Tags: database, moodle

I wonder how the instructor is represented in the vast Moodle DB. Where is the  specific table with attribute columns to store data for every teacher?

Although there is something relevant like the diagram above, i need something to describe the teacher table.

Any ideas?

[image: Moodle ER diagram]

picture taken from : http://www.examulator.com/er/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moodle has the following default archetypes for what you refer to as an instructor;

- manager
- coursecreator
- editingteacher
- teacher

A user can be assigned one of these roles in a particular context, a context such as a course or perhaps course category.

The database stores the teacher data across a number of tables. Looking at the database schema diagram you have shown, the tables you are looking for are in the roles grouping. Specifically role and role_assignments. By linking these tables with the user, context and course tables, you can find the staff associated with courses.

An example function to get the staff associated with a particular course would be

```
function get_course_staff($courseid) {
    global $DB;

    $sql = "SELECT u.firstname,
                   u.lastname
              FROM {role_assignments} ra
             WHERE c.contextlevel = 50 // Numeric value of the course context
               AND c.instanceid = ?
               AND r.id < 5
              JOIN {role} r ON ra.roleid = r.id
              JOIN {user} u ON ra.userid = u.id
              JOIN {context} c ON ra.contextid = c.id
              JOIN {course} co ON c.instanceid = co.id
          ORDER BY r.sortorder ASC";
    return $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array($courseid));
}
```

A role can be assigned to many users.
A user can have many roles.
A user is assigned a role in a particular context.